# SSRS Azure DateTime to LocaldateTime Conversion

Tags: reporting-services, azure-sql-database

I've written a report that extracts the data from SQL Azure storage. Looks like DateTime are stored on server datetime (based on South east asia).

When I render the report the date time is very confusing to the users as it's not a local datetime. Could anyone please suggest how to convert the serverdatetime to local datetime in SSRS, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is not the local datetime but UTC. You can handle all the timestamp and server time by explicitly by converting it to localtime stamp from UTC.